# How to disable 'suggestions' when in content-editable webview [Android]?

Tags: android

There seems to be a bug when you're in a content-editable webview in Android (running 4.03 here) with suggestion of the soft keyboard turned on. It will only show the last typed character after pressing spacebar or something.

**Is there a way to turn-off suggestions when you are in a content-editable webview environment?**